# hotplug of USB devices such as physical keyboard to smartphone Sony Xperia Z3+ e6553 not recognized

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

in order to use USB peripherals on my smartphone thanks to an OTG adapter,

I reinstalled a stock ROM, then flashed a slightly more advanced custom Kernel (`.zip` here https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z4/development/kernel-zachs-kernel-playground-z4-z3-wip-t3404587/page63#629 ), but then when I `$ ls /dev/tty*` within termux I get

`/dev/tty  /dev/ttyHS0  /dev/ttyHSL0`

**and still no `/dev/ttyACM0`, the module that enables communications between smartphone kernel and USB devices, what to do please?**

it's strange because the guy built his kernel from that one https://github.com/AndroPlus-org/android_kernel_sony_msm8994_kitakami_r2/blob/bd618c937401d0fd0371e9223d981b6e466396bf/arch/arm/configs/msm_defconfig#L109 so it should have `ACM`, no?

When I unzip the kernel folder from the 1st link I have `META-INF/`, `modules/`, and `boot.img`, and within modules I have

```
brcm_bt_drv.ko
brcm_hci_ldisc.ko
fm_drv.ko
mcDrvModule.ko
mcKernelApi.ko
mhl_sii8620_8061_drv.ko
```

I assume then that it has some enable-module feature, should I just drag and drop some `.ko` file to get that USB_ACM working?

Comment: There is no smartphon on the market that supports OTG. You mixed it with something else (presumable DR — Dual Role support). And thus the fixing of the problem is quite different.